# GitHub webhook created twice when using Terraform aws_codebuild_webhook

Tags: terraform, githooks, aws-codebuild

I'm creating a an AWS CodeBuild using the following (partial) Terraform Configuration:

```
resource "aws_codebuild_webhook" "webhook" {
  project_name = "${aws_codebuild_project.abc-web-pull-build.name}"
  branch_filter = "master"
}

resource "github_repository_webhook" "webhook" {
  name       = "web"
  repository = "${var.github_repo}"
  active     = true
  events     = ["pull_request"]

  configuration {
    url          = "${aws_codebuild_webhook.webhook.payload_url}"
    content_type = "json"
    insecure_ssl = false
    secret       = "${aws_codebuild_webhook.webhook.secret}"
  }
}
```

for some reason **two** Webhooks are created on GitHub for that spoken project, one with events pull_request and push, and the second with pull request (the only one I've expected).

I've tried removing the first block (aws_codebuild_webhook) even though terraform documentation give an example with both:
https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/codebuild_webhook.html

but than I'm in a pickle because there isn't a way to acquire the payload_url the Webhook require and currently accept it from **aws_codebuild_webhook.webhook.payload_url**.

not sure what is the right approach here, Appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: I've solved the issue by replacing the usage of CodeBuild with code=pipeline, where hooks seem to work as expected for me